# Updating Values within a Simulation in R

Tags: r

I am working on building a model that can predict NFL games, and am looking to run full season simulations and generate expected wins and losses for each team.

Part of the model is based on a rating that changes each week based on whether or not a team lost. For example, lets say the Bills and Ravens each started Sundays game with a rating of 100, after the Ravens win, their rating now increases to 120 and the Bills decrease to 80.

While running the simulation, I would like to update the teams rating throughout in order to get a more accurate representation of the number of ways a season could play out, but am not sure how to include something like this within the loop.

My loop for the 2017 season.

```
full.sim <- NULL

    for(i in 1:10000){
      nflpredictions$sim.homewin <- with(nflpredictions, rbinom(nrow(nflpredictions), 1, homewinpredict)) 
      nflpredictions$winner <- with(nflpredictions, ifelse(sim.homewin, as.character(HomeTeam), as.character(AwayTeam)))
      winningteams <- table(nflpredictions$winner)
      projectedwins <- data.frame(Team=names(winningteams), Wins=as.numeric(winningteams))
      full.sim <- rbind(full.sim, projectedwins)
    }

full.sim <- aggregate(full.sim$Wins, by= list(full.sim$Team), FUN = sum)
full.sim$expectedwins <- full.sim$x / 10000
full.sim$expectedlosses <- 16 - full.sim$expectedwins
```

This works great when running the simulation for 2017 where I already have the full seasons worth of data, but I am having trouble adapting for a model to simulate 2018.

My first idea is to create another for loop within the loop that iterates through the rows and updates the ratings for each week, something along the lines of

```
full.sim <- NULL

        for(i in 1:10000){
            for(i in 1:nrow(nflpredictions)){
```

The idea being to update a teams rating, then generate the win probability for the week using the GLM I have built, simulate who wins, and then continue through the entire dataframe. The only thing really holding me back is not knowing how to add a value to a row based on a row that is not directly above. So what would be the easiest way to update the ratings each week based on the result of the last game that team played in?

The dataframe is built like this, but obviously on a larger scale:

```
nflpredictions

 Week    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HomeRating    AwayRating    HomeProb   AwayProb
 1       BAL         BUF         105           85            .60        .40
 1       NE          HOU         120           90            .65        .35
 2       BUF         LAC         NA            NA            NA         NA
 2       JAX         NE          NA            NA            NA         NA
```

I hope I explained this well enough... Any input is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would recommend having a `ratings` matrix where there is, e.g., a column for each team and a row for each week. At the end of each week, you calculate new ratings and fill in the blanks. Any teams that didn't play keep the same rating. In week `i` you look at the `i`th row of the matrix. This is also nice because you have a record of how each team's rating changed over time.

Comment: More than that, I don't know how to help you unless you include some code in your question. Posting a few rows of **copy/pasteable sample data (not an image)** and some code you've tried would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response! I updated the question with some sample code from the simulation of last years data, and some copy and pastable data. If there is anything else I can do let me know. I like the idea of having a ratings matrix, is there an easy way to build this into the loop?